# Convert DateTime as TimeStamp using jsonSerializable in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, serialization

While we serialize or de-serialize the model using jsonSerializable in Flutter it converts the DateTime as String

```
class Task {
 final DateTime dateTime;
 final String taskName;

 Task({
  required this.dateTime,
  required this.taskName
 }):
}
```

Instead of converting as string it should convert as TimeStamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We can annotate the field with @TimeStampConverter

```
class Task {
 @TimeStampConvertor
 final DateTime dateTime;
 final String taskName;

 Task({
  required this.dateTime,
  required this.taskName
 }):
}
```

2. Create a class for TimeStampConverter

```
class TimestampConverter implements JsonConverter<DateTime, Timestamp> {
  const TimestampConverter();

  @override
  DateTime fromJson(Timestamp timestamp) {
    return timestamp.toDate();
  }

  @override
  Timestamp toJson(DateTime date) => Timestamp.fromDate(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

// For Converting Firebase Timestamp to DateTime
 
 //From Firebase field to Dart Timestamp
 Timestamp _timestamp = doc['dateTime'];
 
 //From Timestamp to Dart DateTime
 DateTime date = _timestamp.toDate();

 //From Dart DateTime to Timestamp
  Timestamp _timestamp =
          Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@JsonKey`. This is a sample from [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable#custom-types-and-custom-encoding) :

```
 @JsonSerializable()
 class Sample3 {
   Sample3(this.value);

   factory Sample3.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
       _$Sample3FromJson(json);

   @JsonKey(
     toJson: _toJson,
     fromJson: _fromJson,
   )
   final DateTime value;

   Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$Sample3ToJson(this);

   static int _toJson(DateTime value) => value.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
   static DateTime _fromJson(int value) =>
       DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(value);
 }
```